# Embeddings of stone-cech boundary of naturals in inseparable compact Hausdorff spaces

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Given a nonseparable compact Hausdorff space $X$ must the stone-cech boundary of the naturals, $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ embed into $X$?

I admittedly don't have too much intuition regarding this. I believe that if $X$ itself appears as a stone-cech boundary of a Tychonoff space then the answer is yes (though I haven't written it down). However the general question seems more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, e.g. ordered compact non-separable Hausdorff spaces, like $\omega_1+1$, or the lexicographically ordered square cannot contain the Cech-Stone remainder of $\mathbb{N}$ (the latter is not hereditarily normal, the former are). I think the Alexandrov double of the $[0,1]$ or the circle is also an easy example (an embedding misses the isolated part, and must lie in the metric part, contradiction). There are probably more easy examples.

Comment: I think you meant $\omega_1+1$, not $\omega +1+1$.

Comment: $|\beta \Bbb N \setminus \Bbb N|=2^{2^{\omega}}$  and there are many inseparable compact Hausdorff spades of smaller cardinality.  There are also other features. E.g. if $S$ is a subspace of $\omega_1+1$ or of the Long Segment, at most one point of $S$ does $not$ have a separable nbhd in $S$ and at most one point in S  does $not$ have countable character in $S$.